# What does /dev/null mean in a shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, filesystem, scripts

I've started learning bash scripting by using this guide: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf

However I got stuck at the first script:

```
cd /var/log
cat /dev/null > messages
cat /dev/null > wtmp
echo "Log files cleaned up."
```

What do lines 2 and 3 do in Ubuntu (I understand `cat`)? Is it only for other Linux distributions? After running this script as root, the output I get is `Log files cleaned up.` But `/var/log` still contains all the files.

Comment: I see 1 problem with this: the 2nd and 3rd line ONLY work with running as root. Otherwise you need `sudo` in front of it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`cat` will list the contents of a file comming after `cat` to standard output and the `>` sends it to the file `messages` and `wtmp` where > means to first remove all contents of the file and >> would mean to ADD to the current file. In this case you are using > so the file will end up being empty.

Now for the kicker: `/dev/null` is a device that sends 'nothing' to the 2 files behind the >.

There is a reason to do it like this: the file is NOT removed from the system. If you would `rm` it and then do a `touch messages` the permissions might be wrong and if just after the `rm` something would want to write to the file it would be gone and error out. Depending on how the software is created it could crash.

Comment: `cat "echo" > messages` will give you a blank file, but also the message `cat: echo: No such file or directory`.  `cat` will relay anything on STDIN, but it doesn't print parameters like `echo` does.  I would personally recommend `echo "" > file` as the intent is clear and unambiguous.

Comment: `echo "" > wtmp` will create an unusable `wtmp` file (as non empty) and then prevent programs that use it to work.

Comment: @Mr.Llama I would recommend that [`truncate`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/truncate) for this - why use an echo and a pipe when there is a command explicitly designed for this task.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Why use a explicitly designed command when no command at all do the same job ? ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Ha! Although I would hate to see your scripts...

Comment: What about `printf "" > wtmp`?

Comment: @jlliagre answer that and you found 1 of the mysteries of coding software ;)

Answer (score 54):

Assuming the commands succeeded, `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/wtmp` still exist but are now *blank*.

### Shell Redirection

`>` is a redirection operator, implemented by the shell. Its syntax is:

```
command > file
```

This redirects *`command`*'s [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) to *`file`*.

- *`file`* may also be a [device node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file).
- If *`file`* doesn't exist, it is created as a [regular file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_file#Regular_file).
- If *`file`* already exists as a regular file and is non-empty, it is overwritten. This is typically the case in the commands you ran, where you redirected the output of `cat /dev/null` to `messages` and `wtmp`.
- If *`file`* already exists as a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), the link's target is used.
- If *`file`* already exists as a directory, you'll get an error like `bash: file: Is a directory`.

(Of course, these operations may fail for other reasons, such as lack of [permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) or a filesystem error.)

The `>>` redirection operator is similar, but it *appends* to the end of non-empty regular files instead of *overwriting* their contents. (Another redirection operator is `<`. `command < file` uses *`file`* as *`command`*'s [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_.28stdin.29).)

### The `null` Device

`/dev/null` is a simple device (implemented in software and not corresponding to any hardware device on the system).

- `/dev/null` looks empty when you read from it.
- Writing to `/dev/null` does nothing: data written to this device simply "disappear."

Often a command's standard output is silenced by redirecting it to `/dev/null`, and this is perhaps the `null` device's commonest use in shell scripting:

```
command > /dev/null
```

You're using `/dev/null` differently. `cat /dev/null` outputs the "contents" of `/dev/null`, which is to say its output is blank. `> messages` (or `> wtmp`) causes this blank output to be redirected to the file on the right side of the `>` operator.

Since `messages` and `wtmp` are regular files (rather than, for example, device nodes), they are turned into blank files (i.e., emptied).

#### You could use any command that does nothing and produces no output, to the left of `>`.

An alternative way to clear these files would be to run:

```
echo -n > messages
echo -n > wtmp
```

The `-n` flag is required, or `echo` writes a [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character.

(This *always works in `bash`*. And I *believe* the default `sh` in every GNU/Linux distribution and other Unix-like system popularly used today supports the `-n` flag in its `echo` builtin. But [jlliagre is right](https://askubuntu.com/a/514985/22949) that [`echo -n` should be avoided for a truly portable shell script, as it's not required to work](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html). Maybe that's why [the guide you're using](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf) teaches the `cat /dev/null` way instead.)

The `echo -n` way is equivalent in its effects but arguably is a better solution, in that it's simpler.
`cat /dev/null > file` opens three "files":

- The `cat` executable (usually `/bin/cat`), a regular file.
- The `/dev/null` device.
- *`file`*

In contrast, `echo -n > file` opens only *`file`* (`echo` is a shell builtin).

Although this should be expected to improve performance, that's not the benefit--not when just running a couple of these commands by hand, anyway. Instead, the benefit is that it's easier to understand what's going on.

#### Redirection and the trivial (blank/empty) command.

*As [**jlliagre has pointed out**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514748/what-does-dev-null-means/514772?noredirect=1#comment697798_514772)* (see also [jlliagre's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/514985/22949)), this can be shortened further by simply omitting the command on the left of `>` altogether. While you cannot omit the right side of a `>` or `>>` expression, the blank command is valid (it's the command you're running when you just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an empty prompt), and in omitting the left side you're just redirecting the output of that command.

- Note that this output does *not* contain a newline. When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a command prompt--whether or not you've typed anything--the shell (running interactively) prints a newline before running the command issued. This newline is not part of the command's output.

Redirecting from the blank command (instead of from `cat /dev/null` or `echo -n`) looks like:

```
> messages
> wtmp
```

Comment: You can go further and replace the useless `echo -n` by `:` or just nothing, given the fact the command does nothing anyway.

Comment: Rather than `echo -n` I would recommend you use [`truncate`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/truncate) - using a command designed for the purpose is, in my option, a little clearer to future readers of the script.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I get your point about readability but the shell can do it a simpler way with an empty redirection.

Comment: @jlliagre You're right: while I thought to suggest `echo -n > messages` as it's self-documenting, it's arguably even better and more instructive to use `> messages`, which is equivalent. **Thank you for pointing this out--I've expanded my answer to cover this option.** (`: > messages` is fine too, though personally I don't particularly care for it--it [has the same meaning](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12405621/1038860) as `true > messages`, `true` also being a shell builtin. If I'm going to to redirect from a named command, `echo -n` is self-documenting as to its purpose lying in its output.)

Answer (score 13):

As already answered, these two lines are clearing the content of the `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/wtmp` files, or are creating them in the unlikely event they do not already exist.

However, they are based on a well established urban legend that gives `/dev/null` "paranormal" powers.

It actually has none so `cat /dev/null` is a waste of keystrokes, time and CPU cycles as it outputs absolutely nothing. Eliah Kagan's reply suggests the better approach which is using `echo -n` instead. This is better but not portable to some shells/OSes where it might put the '`-n`' string into these files.

You can go further and replace these commands by the portable and simpler:

```
cd /var/log
: > messages
: > wtmp
echo "Log files cleaned up."
```

With most shells (but not the `csh` based ones), you can go even further and remove the no-op command '`:`' :

```
cd /var/log
> messages
> wtmp
echo "Log files cleaned up."
```

Comment: I see the benefit of redirecting from `:` (rather than from nothing) in that it will work with non-Bourne-style shells, such as csh/tcsh. Are there also Bourne-style shells that won't redirect stdout from an empty command?

Comment: @EliahKagan No Bourne style shell I'm aware of won't redirect stdout from an empty command. This was already the case with the  Unix version 7 (1979) original Bourne shell.

Answer (score 6):

`>` is output redirecting operator. It will redirect the output of  command to file mentioned after it instead of standard output device, truncating or overwriting file's contents.

for example `ls -l > demo.txt`. After executing this command, "demo.txt"
 will contain th output `ls -l` command.

Now next thing is what is this `/dev/null`.`/dev/null` is the null file Is is a special file which contains nothing.

So when you execute commands

```
cat /dev/null > messages
cat /dev/null > wtmp
```

it clears the contents of  "messages" and "wtmp" file by overwriting with EOF(End Of File) character.

So here you are not clearing your `/var/log` directory, but you are clearing the contents of these two files.

Answer (score 1):

/dev/null is like a  black hole. Writes made to the /dev/null are discarded. In this script, they are using /dev/null to empty the message log file.

Otherwise they could have simply used.

```
 > /var/log/messages.
```

There are other ways to empty the contents of a file.

Like.

```
     truncate  -s  0  /var/log/messages
     cp  /dev/null  /var/log/messages
```

But using ">" or "/dev/null" is the efficient way.