# syslog and kern.log multiple GB in size filled with pcieport error messages

Tags: 14.04, kernel, syslog, logs, pcie

After getting a disk usage warning, I noticed my `syslog` and `kern.log` were multiple GBs in size (20GB each). I then used this [askubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do) to clear the log files but today I find that they have again grown to around 2GB in size. This is a normal computer which is shutdown at the end of the day so these files have literally grown that much in a day or two. The last 10,000 lines of both log files can be downloaded; [syslog](https://www.dropbox.com/s/go7g99wu6onwdzv/syslog?dl=0) and [kern.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uli3l3658u3lzm3/kern.log?dl=0). I then examined the contents of my log files and noticed a repeating message

```
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119288] pcieport 0000:00:07.0: can't find device of ID0038
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119290] pcieport 0000:00:07.0: AER: Corrected error received: id=0038
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119297] pcieport 0000:00:07.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=0038(Receiver ID)
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119298] pcieport 0000:00:07.0:   device [8086:340e] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119299] pcieport 0000:00:07.0:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119303] pcieport 0000:00:07.0: AER: Corrected error received: id=0038
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119307] pcieport 0000:00:07.0: can't find device of ID0038
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119313] pcieport 0000:00:07.0: AER: Corrected error received: id=0038
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119322] pcieport 0000:00:07.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=0038(Receiver ID)
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119324] pcieport 0000:00:07.0:   device [8086:340e] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119329] pcieport 0000:00:07.0:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119333] pcieport 0000:00:07.0: AER: Corrected error received: id=0038
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119348] pcieport 0000:00:07.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=0038(Receiver ID)
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119349] pcieport 0000:00:07.0:   device [8086:340e] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119350] pcieport 0000:00:07.0:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119356] pcieport 0000:00:07.0: AER: Corrected error received: id=0038
Aug 20 10:47:41 macallan3 kernel: [  382.119360] pcieport 0000:00:07.0: can't find device of ID0038
```

The complete output of `lspci` is also available; [lspci](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h0l1zrg4u2803ge/lspci.txt?dl=0). PCI ID 0000:00:07.0: corresponds to

```
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev 13)
```

Now any ideas what's going on? Is my PCIe port failing? Or what's connected to the PCIe express port failing? I should note I think my Nvidia card is connected to that PCIe port.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Very large log files, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do)