# var/log/syslog growing indefinitely in size

Tags: files, disk-usage, log, syslog

The disk that contains Ubuntu on my computer is `115GB` in size.

When the disk was `114.7GB`full.

I started deleting some files here and there to free up around `5GB`.

But I noticed the disk was `114GB` filled again. I thought it was some cache or swap thingy so didn't give it much thought and went ahead and freed around `40GB`by shifting some media files out of the disk.

I have a notification in an hour or so that the disk is full yet again!!
`40GB`!!! All gone!

So I debugged the problem down to the `/var/log/syslog` file which was initially definitely less than `20GB`. I know this because `/var` folder was `17GB` before I cleared the memory.

`/var/log/syslog` file is currently `55.9GB`!

Could someone be so gracious to explain this anomaly?
Is this a bug?
Or am I affected with some malware or virus?

Comment: are you using a VPN by chance?

Comment: It depends what all apps and stuff running in your system? You can clean some of the old/archived entries under /var/log(recursively) which are *.gz. But you watch under /var/log in terms of why some of the logs are growing so fast?

Comment: Ashu is right... Perhaps edit your question to tell us what entries in the log file are causing it to grow so quickly

Comment: Well, have a *look* in /var/syslog, and see what is filling it up!

Comment: +1 ... you might want to use something like `tail -f /var/log/syslog` from a terminal (to avoid having to load such a large file into a text editor)

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Yes I am but I have been using it for a long time now.

Comment: Yeah I checked the file it is the error of the wifi monitor `mon0` I ran. Cant believe it flooded 50GB. The same error XD

Comment: I asked that because brute force attacks can often lead to huge log files, but those are usually different logs. It looks like you found the culprit though. You may want to ask a new question about the wifi monitor mon0 problem to see how to get that solved.

Comment: I see @KalamalkaKid. Yeah you are right, have to see what mon0 leads to. Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Very large log files, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do)

Comment: One possible cause for syslog quickly filling up disk space: nvidia driver + VLC. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561565/

Answer (score 30):

This indefinite growth generally occurs due to repeated log of one or more errors from the same source. 
In my case it was due to continual report of connection error from the wifi monitoring interface `mon0` I have used to monitor my wifi traffic.
There have been error reports of such overflow occurring in various other interfaces like `tun0` from VPN etc.

I have resolved my issue by clearing the `/var/log/syslog` file

To tackle this error

1. You need to **find the source of this error and stop it** from producing any further overflow of log
2. Then **clear** the `var/log/syslog` file

Problems you might face doing the same

1. **Cant open `var/log/syslog`:** due to massive size any editor is bound to crash
2. **Cant clear `/var/log/syslog`:** Again due to massive size clearing is a challenge too

So, for viewing the error that caused the overflow

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

For clearing use:

```
sudo cat /dev/null > /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 12):

I had similar issues, my syslog file had 115GB and syslog.1 another 115G, plus multiple compressed files.

1st step
find the source:

```
watch tail /var/log/syslog
```

you will probably notice the common erro entries;
after that; assuming that your files are too big; it is ALMOST pointless to rotate.
So, you can delete all the compressed files and files *.1 to recover disk space (my case about 300GB)

2nd step
TRUNCATE THE FILE, DO NOT DELETE (or you may have a lot of problems with permissions in the future), there are many methods, including:

```
sudo tee /var/log/syslog </dev/null
```

you can even do the second step before and keep watching to find the cause, but be sure, if you don't it will happen again. Probably it is something in a loop, system services is a good place to start looking (something that restart very fast and always for exemple)

Comment: I don't know why but `sudo tee /var/log/syslog </dev/null` command worked. But I was expecting `sudo cat /dev/null > /var/log/syslog` work too but didn't work :/

Answer (score 3):

Check the `/var/lib/logrotate/status` and make sure that it's getting rotated properly. You also need to view the contents of the file and see if it's a system issue throwing alarms constantly.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It should work correctly and clean it up:

```
sudo sh -c 'cat /dev/null > /var/log/syslog'
```

Comment: This seems more to be hiding the symptoms than fixing the problem.

Comment: sudo truncate -s 0 /var/log/syslog

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Create a script file example clearlog.sh in location /var/log/ with file permission 'chmod 775 clearlog.sh'

clearlog.sh file with below lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
LINECOUNTS=(`cat /var/log/syslog | wc -l`)

if [ $LINECOUNTS -gt "1000" ];
    then
        echo "Recreating syslog file due to lines "$LINECOUNTS" are more than 1000 lines"
        truncate -s 0 /var/log/syslog
        sleep 5
else
        echo "syslog file having line count "$LINECOUNTS" less than 1000}"
fi
/bin/systemctl restart syslog
exit
```

**Step 2:** Edit the file in location /etc/logrotate.d/logs add postrotate section

```
/var/log/syslog {
        daily
        rotate 3
        missingok
        copy
        notifempty
        compress
        dateext
        dateformat -%Y%m%d%H%M
        postrotate
                /var/log/clearlog.sh
        endscript
}
```

To test above script from command terminal execute this cli 'logrotate -f /etc/logrotate/logs'

Answer (score 0):

A late response to the original post but this helped me. When running a program as a service it seems that all printfs are diverted to syslog rather than stdout, if you have a lot of printfs then this will fill up the syslog very quickly. I had some issues with some of the methods suggested here but

sudo tee /var/log/syslog </dev/null

worked every time.

Note that (for me) I when the syslog file filled up enough it prevented the pi desktop from starting up - I worked around this by logging in through Putty and using the tee command first then rebooting.

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong way to handle the problem. The logfile is filling up fora reason - find out why and fix the problem(s). Deleting (old) logfiles can be a work-around ubtil the real problem is fixed. Deleting / emptying the active logfile (here /var/log/syslog) will normally not release the disk-space before the file is closed by restarting the syslog service or rebooting the machine.

Answer (score -1):

Installing shurfshark snap made my syslog max out my hard drive in a day. Uninstalled and it appears to be stable in size now.