# Disk space depleting fast - what should I do?

Tags: disk-usage, free

I'm on 16.04. 
Free disk space keeps on getting smaller by the hour in Gigabytes.
I'm not downloading anything or installing anything.

Yesterday I ran timeshift, and I regained 20GB+ of free space.
This morning it went again to no disk space available.
I did another second system restore on timeshift & I'm monitoring the free space and it's depleting again at a fast rate.

I ran Disk usage analyzer, but I'm not sure which one is getting bloated by the minute.

I deleted files,trash and apps,but free space is not increasing,not until I do system restore.

what could be causing this?

```
$ sudo du -hxd1 /
152K    /tmp
16M /bin
3.3G    /root
690M    /lib
2.1G    /mnt
110M    /boot
369M    /timeshift
4.0K    /cdrom
20K /media
566M    /opt
4.6G    /usr
21M /etc
1.7G    /home
20K /snap
16M /sbin
16K /lost+found
4.0K    /lib64
15G /var
4.0K    /srv
29G /
```

```
$ sudo lsof | grep deleted
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
php-fpm7.  1557             root    3u      REG                8,5            0    1703940 /tmp/.ZendSem.JsVNUw (deleted)
php-fpm7.  1561         www-data    3u      REG                8,5            0    1703940 /tmp/.ZendSem.JsVNUw (deleted)
php-fpm7.  1562         www-data    3u      REG                8,5            0    1703940 /tmp/.ZendSem.JsVNUw (deleted)
upstart    5558                a   17w      REG                8,5          298     525093 /home/a/.cache/upstart/at-spi2-registryd.log.1 (deleted)
upstart    5558                a   18w      REG                8,5           85     525213 /home/a/.cache/upstart/window-stack-bridge.log.1 (deleted)
upstart    5558                a   19w      REG                8,5          219     525214 /home/a/.cache/upstart/indicator-messages.log.1 (deleted)
upstart    5558                a   22w      REG                8,5         5667     535003 /home/a/.cache/upstart/indicator-sound.log.1 (deleted)
bamfdaemo  5744                a   13r      REG                8,5         4964     525067 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
bamfdaemo  5744                a   14r      REG                8,5        32768     525069 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-143156af.log (deleted)
dconf\x20  5744  5800          a   13r      REG                8,5         4964     525067 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
dconf\x20  5744  5800          a   14r      REG                8,5        32768     525069 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-143156af.log (deleted)
gmain      5744  5805          a   13r      REG                8,5         4964     525067 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
gmain      5744  5805          a   14r      REG                8,5        32768     525069 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-143156af.log (deleted)
gdbus      5744  5806          a   13r      REG                8,5         4964     525067 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
gdbus      5744  5806          a   14r      REG                8,5        32768     525069 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-143156af.log (deleted)
pool       5744 24208          a   13r      REG                8,5         4964     525067 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
pool       5744 24208          a   14r      REG                8,5        32768     525069 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-143156af.log (deleted)
tracker-e  5902                a   12r      REG                8,5         4964     525032 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
tracker-e  5902                a   13r      REG                8,5        32768     525039 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-8455b860.log (deleted)
dconf\x20  5902  5952          a   12r      REG                8,5         4964     525032 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
dconf\x20  5902  5952          a   13r      REG                8,5        32768     525039 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-8455b860.log (deleted)
gmain      5902  5954          a   12r      REG                8,5         4964     525032 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
gmain      5902  5954          a   13r      REG                8,5        32768     525039 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-8455b860.log (deleted)
gdbus      5902  5955          a   12r      REG                8,5         4964     525032 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
gdbus      5902  5955          a   13r      REG                8,5        32768     525039 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-8455b860.log (deleted)
pool       5902  5958          a   12r      REG                8,5         4964     525032 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
pool       5902  5958          a   13r      REG                8,5        32768     525039 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-8455b860.log (deleted)
pool       5902  5959          a   12r      REG                8,5         4964     525032 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
pool       5902  5959          a   13r      REG                8,5        32768     525039 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-8455b860.log (deleted)
pool       5902  5960          a   12r      REG                8,5         4964     525032 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
pool       5902  5960          a   13r      REG                8,5        32768     525039 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-8455b860.log (deleted)
pool       5902  5961          a   12r      REG                8,5         4964     525032 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
pool       5902  5961          a   13r      REG                8,5        32768     525039 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-8455b860.log (deleted)
pool       5902  5962          a   12r      REG                8,5         4964     525032 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
pool       5902  5962          a   13r      REG                8,5        32768     525039 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-8455b860.log (deleted)
pool       5902  5963          a   12r      REG                8,5         4964     525032 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
pool       5902  5963          a   13r      REG                8,5        32768     525039 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-8455b860.log (deleted)
pool       5902  5964          a   12r      REG                8,5         4964     525032 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
pool       5902  5964          a   13r      REG                8,5        32768     525039 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-8455b860.log (deleted)
pool       5902  5965          a   12r      REG                8,5         4964     525032 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
pool       5902  5965          a   13r      REG                8,5        32768     525039 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-8455b860.log (deleted)
pool       5902  5966          a   12r      REG                8,5         4964     525032 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
pool       5902  5966          a   13r      REG                8,5        32768     525039 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-8455b860.log (deleted)
pool       5902  5967          a   12r      REG                8,5         4964     525032 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
pool       5902  5967          a   13r      REG                8,5        32768     525039 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-8455b860.log (deleted)
nautilus   6216                a   14r      REG                8,5        14448     525314 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home (deleted)
nautilus   6216                a   17r      REG                8,5        32768     525322 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home-d214801e.log (deleted)
nautilus   6216                a   20r      REG                8,5       123860     525323 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
nautilus   6216                a   21r      REG                8,5        32768     525324 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-7b825e19.log (deleted)
gmain      6216  6231          a   14r      REG                8,5        14448     525314 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home (deleted)
gmain      6216  6231          a   17r      REG                8,5        32768     525322 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home-d214801e.log (deleted)
gmain      6216  6231          a   20r      REG                8,5       123860     525323 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
gmain      6216  6231          a   21r      REG                8,5        32768     525324 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-7b825e19.log (deleted)
gdbus      6216  6232          a   14r      REG                8,5        14448     525314 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home (deleted)
gdbus      6216  6232          a   17r      REG                8,5        32768     525322 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home-d214801e.log (deleted)
gdbus      6216  6232          a   20r      REG                8,5       123860     525323 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
gdbus      6216  6232          a   21r      REG                8,5        32768     525324 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-7b825e19.log (deleted)
dconf\x20  6216  6234          a   14r      REG                8,5        14448     525314 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home (deleted)
dconf\x20  6216  6234          a   17r      REG                8,5        32768     525322 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home-d214801e.log (deleted)
dconf\x20  6216  6234          a   20r      REG                8,5       123860     525323 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
dconf\x20  6216  6234          a   21r      REG                8,5        32768     525324 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-7b825e19.log (deleted)
nautilus   6216  6244          a   14r      REG                8,5        14448     525314 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home (deleted)
nautilus   6216  6244          a   17r      REG                8,5        32768     525322 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home-d214801e.log (deleted)
nautilus   6216  6244          a   20r      REG                8,5       123860     525323 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
nautilus   6216  6244          a   21r      REG                8,5        32768     525324 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-7b825e19.log (deleted)
pool       6216  6851          a   14r      REG                8,5        14448     525314 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home (deleted)
pool       6216  6851          a   17r      REG                8,5        32768     525322 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home-d214801e.log (deleted)
pool       6216  6851          a   20r      REG                8,5       123860     525323 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
pool       6216  6851          a   21r      REG                8,5        32768     525324 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-7b825e19.log (deleted)
pool       6216  6852          a   14r      REG                8,5        14448     525314 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home (deleted)
pool       6216  6852          a   17r      REG                8,5        32768     525322 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home-d214801e.log (deleted)
pool       6216  6852          a   20r      REG                8,5       123860     525323 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
pool       6216  6852          a   21r      REG                8,5        32768     525324 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-7b825e19.log (deleted)
pool       6216  6853          a   14r      REG                8,5        14448     525314 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home (deleted)
pool       6216  6853          a   17r      REG                8,5        32768     525322 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home-d214801e.log (deleted)
pool       6216  6853          a   20r      REG                8,5       123860     525323 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
pool       6216  6853          a   21r      REG                8,5        32768     525324 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-7b825e19.log (deleted)
pool       6216  6854          a   14r      REG                8,5        14448     525314 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home (deleted)
pool       6216  6854          a   17r      REG                8,5        32768     525322 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home-d214801e.log (deleted)
pool       6216  6854          a   20r      REG                8,5       123860     525323 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
pool       6216  6854          a   21r      REG                8,5        32768     525324 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-7b825e19.log (deleted)
unity-sco  6882                a    9u      REG                8,5        65536    1703948 /tmp/tmpfSKb0O4 (deleted)
unity-sco  6882                a   10u      REG                8,5        32768    1703949 /tmp/tmpfTvJQCQ (deleted)
unity-sco  6882                a   11u      REG                8,5        32768    1703950 /tmp/tmpf03pLqC (deleted)
unity-sco  6882                a   12u      REG                8,5        16384    1703962 /tmp/tmpf74Hxqo (deleted)
unity-sco  6882                a   13u      REG                8,5        16384    1703965 /tmp/tmpfA85rqa (deleted)
dconf\x20  6882  6885          a    9u      REG                8,5        65536    1703948 /tmp/tmpfSKb0O4 (deleted)
dconf\x20  6882  6885          a   10u      REG                8,5        32768    1703949 /tmp/tmpfTvJQCQ (deleted)
dconf\x20  6882  6885          a   11u      REG                8,5        32768    1703950 /tmp/tmpf03pLqC (deleted)
dconf\x20  6882  6885          a   12u      REG                8,5        16384    1703962 /tmp/tmpf74Hxqo (deleted)
dconf\x20  6882  6885          a   13u      REG                8,5        16384    1703965 /tmp/tmpfA85rqa (deleted)
gmain      6882  6886          a    9u      REG                8,5        65536    1703948 /tmp/tmpfSKb0O4 (deleted)
gmain      6882  6886          a   10u      REG                8,5        32768    1703949 /tmp/tmpfTvJQCQ (deleted)
gmain      6882  6886          a   11u      REG                8,5        32768    1703950 /tmp/tmpf03pLqC (deleted)
gmain      6882  6886          a   12u      REG                8,5        16384    1703962 /tmp/tmpf74Hxqo (deleted)
gmain      6882  6886          a   13u      REG                8,5        16384    1703965 /tmp/tmpfA85rqa (deleted)
gdbus      6882  6887          a    9u      REG                8,5        65536    1703948 /tmp/tmpfSKb0O4 (deleted)
gdbus      6882  6887          a   10u      REG                8,5        32768    1703949 /tmp/tmpfTvJQCQ (deleted)
gdbus      6882  6887          a   11u      REG                8,5        32768    1703950 /tmp/tmpf03pLqC (deleted)
gdbus      6882  6887          a   12u      REG                8,5        16384    1703962 /tmp/tmpf74Hxqo (deleted)
gdbus      6882  6887          a   13u      REG                8,5        16384    1703965 /tmp/tmpfA85rqa (deleted)
gvfsd-rec 11009                a   15r      REG                8,5       123848     525304 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
gvfsd-rec 11009                a   16r      REG                8,5        32768     525307 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-beb4670b.log (deleted)
gvfsd-rec 11009                a   19r      REG                8,5         4964     525067 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
gvfsd-rec 11009                a   20r      REG                8,5        32768     525069 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-143156af.log (deleted)
gmain     11009 11010          a   15r      REG                8,5       123848     525304 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
gmain     11009 11010          a   16r      REG                8,5        32768     525307 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-beb4670b.log (deleted)
gmain     11009 11010          a   19r      REG                8,5         4964     525067 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
gmain     11009 11010          a   20r      REG                8,5        32768     525069 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-143156af.log (deleted)
gdbus     11009 11011          a   15r      REG                8,5       123848     525304 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
gdbus     11009 11011          a   16r      REG                8,5        32768     525307 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-beb4670b.log (deleted)
gdbus     11009 11011          a   19r      REG                8,5         4964     525067 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
gdbus     11009 11011          a   20r      REG                8,5        32768     525069 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-143156af.log (deleted)
dconf\x20 11009 11014          a   15r      REG                8,5       123848     525304 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
dconf\x20 11009 11014          a   16r      REG                8,5        32768     525307 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-beb4670b.log (deleted)
dconf\x20 11009 11014          a   19r      REG                8,5         4964     525067 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root (deleted)
dconf\x20 11009 11014          a   20r      REG                8,5        32768     525069 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/root-143156af.log (deleted)
gedit     13965                a   15r      REG                8,5       123860     525323 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
gedit     13965                a   16r      REG                8,5        32768     525324 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-7b825e19.log (deleted)
gmain     13965 13967          a   15r      REG                8,5       123860     525323 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
gmain     13965 13967          a   16r      REG                8,5        32768     525324 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-7b825e19.log (deleted)
gdbus     13965 13968          a   15r      REG                8,5       123860     525323 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
gdbus     13965 13968          a   16r      REG                8,5        32768     525324 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-7b825e19.log (deleted)
dconf\x20 13965 13969          a   15r      REG                8,5       123860     525323 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D (deleted)
dconf\x20 13965 13969          a   16r      REG                8,5        32768     525324 /home/a/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/uuid-9AB47E74B47E532D-7b825e19.log (deleted)
```

[image: disk usage showing /var filling up]

```
128M    /var/lib/clamav/daily.cld
175M    /var/log/kern.log.1
351M    /var/lib/clamav
822M    /var/lib/apt
822M    /var/lib/apt/lists
1.4G    /var/lib
11G /var/log/kern.log
11G /var/log/syslog
22G /var/log
24G /var/
```

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Mar  9 15:21:07 a-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [16010.524133]  [<ffffffff8109cd30>] ? process_one_work+0x490/0x490
Mar  9 15:21:07 a-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [16010.524135]  [<ffffffff810a30f7>] kthread+0xe7/0x100
Mar  9 15:21:07 a-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [16010.524138]  [<ffffffff810a3010>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
Mar  9 15:21:07 a-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [16010.524142]  [<ffffffff8184f422>] ret_from_fork+0x42/0x80
Mar  9 15:21:07 a-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [16010.524144]  [<ffffffff810a3010>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
Mar  9 15:21:07 a-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [16010.524146] ---[ end trace 54cfa3b88295de72 ]---
Mar  9 15:21:07 a-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [16010.525789] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Mar  9 15:21:07 a-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [16010.525798] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 29462 at /build/linux-fQ94TU/linux-4.4.0/drivers/usb/core/urb.c:449 usb_submit_urb.part.6+0x142/0x560()
Mar  9 15:21:07 a-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [16010.525801] usb 8-2: BOGUS urb xfer, pipe 1 != type 3
Mar  9 15:21:07 a-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M kernel: [16010.525803] Modules linked in: ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos jfs xfs libcrc32c ndiswrapper(OE) drbg ansi_cprng ctr ccm bnep msr nfnetlink_queue nfnetlink_log nfnetlink bluetooth ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 nf_nat_h323 nf_conntrack_h323 nf_nat_pptp nf_nat_proto_gre nf_conntrack_pptp nf_conntrack_proto_gre nf_nat_tftp nf_conntrack_tftp nf_nat_sip nf_conntrack_sip nf_nat_irc nf_conntrack_irc iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) arc4 ath9k_htc ath9k_common ath9k_hw ath mac80211 cfg80211 kvm_amd kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul joydev input_leds glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event serio_raw snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer k10temp snd 8250_fintek soundcore shpchp i2c_piix4 tpm_infineon mac_hid binfmt_misc ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 nf_log_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common xt_LOG xt_limit xt_tcpudp xt_addrtype nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 xt_conntrack ip6table_filter ip6_tables nf_conntrack_netbios_ns nf_conntrack_broadcast nf_nat_ftp nf_nat nf_conntrack_ftp nf_c
```

Comment: Add the output of `sudo du -hxd1 /` and `sudo lsof | grep deleted`, please.

Comment: are those are two separate commands without the slash after hxd1?   for :  sudo lsof | grep deleted  and sudo du -hxd1     .. The result is too long,its not allowing me to paste it here.

Comment: sudo du -hxd1 / and sudo lsof | grep deleted    results :    du: cannot access 'and': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'sudo': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'lsof': No such file or directory

Comment: Yes,I tried them as two separate commands but results are too long to paste in the comment section.Its not allowing to paste it

Comment: it's a system log ... I had a bug with another system. I forget the process that caused it, but looking at the log will tell you. Basically a USB error was being written to the log several times a second.

Comment: sorry,post updated for sudo du -hxd1 /

Comment: what have you got in /var ? it is 15G.

Comment: pls see pic above

Comment: It's probably what @ravery says, a bloated log file. Run this command to see which files are largest in `/var` (the entire thing as a single line): `sudo du -axh /var/ | sort -h | tail`

Comment: post updated above.. yes,log file is growing indeed. :(  how come?

Comment: a related topic here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/746535/var-log-syslog-growing-indefinitely-in-size but it does not say how to trace&fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[Very large log files, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do/515152#515152)

I used the last part. So far the log files are not growing since.

```
sudo apt-get install busybox-syslogd
```

After installing that package, reset syslog and kern.log:

```
sudo tee /var/log/syslog /var/log/kern.log </dev/null
```

thank you everyone

Comment: Removing large log-files frees diskspace, But it doesn't solve the real problem - What makes logfiles grow. You will have to analyze the logs and solve the real problem.