# log files taking over the disk on new computer. Help?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, disk, disk-usage

Just built my first pc and I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 (just that, not dual booting) I've got a 225 SSD and a TB HDD. Long story short, all was well and good until I ran out of memory like 3 weeks later ---> realized the TB HDD wasn't mounted, I mounted it and I'm still low on memory.

I thought it was a partitioning problem until someone pointed out it was my log file getting out of control. It's getting filled up real quick and I'm not sure how to go about it.

Here are the last 100 lines /var/log/kern.log hang on guys, its a doozie.

```
Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.304085] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.304991] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.304993] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.304995] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.305876] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.305877] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)


Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.305879] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.306759] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.306761] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.306763] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.307765] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.307767] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.307769] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.308650] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.308652] ACPI Error: 
Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.308654] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.309534] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.309535] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.309537] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.310416] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.310418] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.310420] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.311300] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.311302] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.311304] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.312312] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.312313] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.312316] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.313195] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.313196] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.313198] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.314078] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.314080] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.314082] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.314962] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.314964] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.314966] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.315968] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.315969] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.315972] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.316851] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.316852] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.316854] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.317734] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.317736] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.317738] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.318617] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.318619] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.318621] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.319630] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.319632] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.319634] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.320527] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.320528] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.320530] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.321438] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.321439] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.321441] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.322322] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.322323] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.322326] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.323205] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.323207] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.323209] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.324238] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.324240] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.324242] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.325196] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.325198] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.325200] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.326119] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.326121] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.326123] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.327293] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.327295] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.327297] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.328488] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.328490] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.328494] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.329411] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.329413] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.329415] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.330294] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.330296] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.330298] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.331178] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.331180] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.331182] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.332224] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.332226] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.332228] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.333150] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.333152] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.333154] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.334033] ACPI Error: 
[PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.334035] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.334037] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.334916] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psargs-359)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.334917] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8808544df460), AE_NOT_FOUND (20150930/psparse-542)

Nov 26 18:53:34 underyourbed-desktop kernel: [ 2713.334920] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20150930/evgpe-592)
```

Comment: Something on your computer is using way too much space.  /var holds log files and such.  We need to know which folder or folders have gotten enormous.  Try running `du -a /var | sort -n -r | head -n 10`, which should report the ten largest folders inside /var.  If replying directly to me in a comment, put an ampersand followed by my user name in the comment, or else I'll never see it.

Comment: @rclocher3 
   
    189538064 /var
    188615256 /var/log
    92915244 /var/log/kern.log 
    72834572 /var/log/kern.log.1
    16598220 /var/log/syslog
    4056076 /var/log/syslog.1
    1014724 /var/log/kern.log.2.gz
    603140 /var/cache
    582872 /var/cache/apt
    494440 /var/cache/apt/archives

Comment: What brand/model system/motherboard. Some need boot parameters. My /var is: 1181260 /var  But I do houseclean old .gz files regularly if no issues. So you have some log file running away.  Best to check what is posting & reposting.

Comment: @oldfred i got an ASRock  H170A-X1/3.1 motherboard.  How do I check what it's posting/reposting? Also, thanks for chiming in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log files are getting out of control.  If your computer is new, then you need to discover why the log files are so huge, but first you'll need to truncate, compress, or delete the log files in order for your system to have enough room to work.  [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do) tells what to do to make the log files smaller.  But you should try and figure out what's going wrong before you delete all the log files.

I'd recommend that you edit the title of your question to something along the lines of "log files taking over the disk on new computer", since you have a log file problem rather than a partition problem.  Editing your question should "bump" it so that it gets more attention.  Also edit your question to show about the last 100 lines of `/var/log/kern.log`, the kernel log, which is your largest log file.  You need to discover what is wrong that makes the log fill up so fast.

If you need to make more room immediately for the system to work, you can delete a few of the older log files.

To see the last 100 lines of kern.log, you can do this command on the command line: `tail -n 100 /var/log/kern.log > ~/kern.log.truncated`.  That copies the last 100 lines of the log file to `kern.log.truncated` in your home folder, so you can paste it into your question.

Comment: thanks, I'll probably start a new thread or something. There's another weird symptom: when my SSD is full, I try to save stuff on my flash drive or my HDD and the pc'll tell me that I don't have enough space.... Which is real weird.

Comment: I did a web search for "ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND" and got lots of hits, lots of people with similar problems to yours.  You should check it out.

Comment: Looked it up.  Looks like a BIOS bug? I updated my BIOS aaaaaaaaand things look pretty normal I guess. Think I should clean up and see if the logs fill up again?

Comment: Great!  Yeah, that's what I'd recommend.  By the way, if I've been helpful please consider upvoting my answer or accepting it.

Comment: Thanks so much, we're gonna need some toilet paper because you're the shit. Last thing, how do I clean up the log files? I know I can delete the .gz stuff but what about the kern.log stuff? That looks like the one that takes up the most space . _.

Comment: Awww...  :)  I'm pretty happy that I was able to help, but I would like some reputation points to show for it, so please do considering upvoting or accepting.  As for kern.log, I think you can safely delete it or gzip it, because the system will just recreate it.  It did its job: it helped you discover that there was a problem with the BIOS that needed fixing.