# log files getting big fast

Tags: files, log

Please help me determine the cause.  
 
 It is gaining 2gb per hour approximately. 
   So far,its only happening when I try using the wifi adapter thru usb to rj45 adapter.  The extension chord is badly needed for proper signal.

Comment: Which log(s) specifically? have you examined them to see what the messages are? See for example [Very large log files, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do/515152#515152)

Comment: @steeldriver.  thank you very much for the link.  i think the last part of your link got my issue fixed. the one that says: $ sudo apt-get install busybox-syslogd

After installing that package, reset syslog and kern.log:

sudo tee /var/log/syslog /var/log/kern.log </dev/null