# After new 18.04 install to 1 TB SDD - disks utility shows percentage full, kernel.log constantly increasing - pci=noaer added to kernel command line

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I just did a fresh install on a 1 TB SDD. Install is fine. I checked the disk using Disks and I see the percentage full continuously increasing. Why is this happening?

I noticed that I don't see a swap partition - could that be the reason?

[image]

[image]

Now the full space is up to 11.9% and keeps increasing.

[image]

Comment: First of all, use your investigative skills to find out who is eating your disk space. A good starting point would be `sudo du -ms /* 2> /dev/null | sort -nr`, which will give you a list of top level directories sorted in descending order of used disk space. Then pick one and drill down.

Comment: Thanks, AlexP for your comment. I used 'sudo du -ms /* 2> /dev/null | sort -nr' and found out that files are growing in /home and no other location. I left my system off today to save disk space. When I turned it on, the percent full started increasing again and then I saw a system error: Details: polkit.subject-pid: 2179 / polkit.caller-pid: 3574 Action: com.Ubuntu.apport.apport-gtk-root - the error report that generated the internal error has a section - JournalErrors - PCIe Bus Error:severity=Corrected,type=Physical Layer - there are 10 or more of these. The disk I installed to is 1 TB SSD.

Comment: Found the source: /var/log/ - this log directory is 317 GB and keeps growing. HD is 34% full and keeps growing.

Comment: kern.log is 163 GB and syslog.1 is 164 GB

Comment: I believe I have implemented a solution. I will monitor overnight and post solution details tomorrow if all is well. So far disk utilization is 'normal'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While searching for information regarding kern.log and syslog.1, I found a [page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do) to zero the file size. I performed this after I resolved the source of the problem.

The source was that in the background, I had a constant error regarding PCIe Bus Error. This was throwing line after line scrolling on the screen and I didn't see it until I shut the machine down.

Searching for the PCIe Bus Error led me to this [page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329403/my-var-log-is-mysteriously-filling-up-gbs-in-minutes): it describes how to apply the fix. This worked for me.

you need to add pci=noaer to your kernel command line.

Following the instruction on the page mentioned, the errors stopped and no further space was taken up by logs.

I then zeroed the kern.log and syslog.1 which had become very large - over 160 GB using the 'Shortest method:' from this [page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do).

What resolved the issue?

1. Add pci=noaer to kernel command line
2. zero log files kernel.log and syslog.1

Comment: +1 to both your question and answer. Can you change the title to include ` pci=noaer` and/or Kern.log to make it more searchable by others?