# Constantly increasing size of syslog} Why I have(had) very large size of /var/log?

Tags: 18.04, disk-usage, log, syslog

I am on Ubuntu 18.04

I was constantly getting `Filesystem.root not enough space` warnings. So, I searched on the web a little bit and learned how to inspect disk usage by,

`sudo baobab`

Then I saw that, `/var/log` was 74 GBs and I surprised. I looked inside that directory and saw `sys.log` was almost 72 GBs.

I have solved the issue by emptying the content of that `syslog` document by following the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/515151/1040069).

For now, it looks like it is solved, however *I wonder what might have been the reason for such large log file? Is that usual?*

Thanks.

### UPDATE

I now figured out that I haven't solve anything, it just filled up to 30 GB again in minutes, so I guess something is wrong,

I inspected `syslog` by

```
cat syslog | more
```

Some part of the output is :

```
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer attributes failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer rendering failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
 mixer features failure: An invalid handle value was provided.
Mar 21 10:06:38 muyustan-ubuntu org.gnome.Nautilus[1577]: [00007fb0a087e5b0] vdpau_chroma filter error: video
```

NOW, it looks like I am getting infinitely many errors in seconds, and it fills up the `syslog` document. However, I am incapable of locating what is the problem and how should I correct it.

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't said what OS/release you are talking about, and I don't know /var/log/sys.log but you could be talking about /var/log/syslog.   If it's that large I would explore it and look for what is creating all the messages and look at cause, not the symptom.

Comment: @guiverc, Thanks, I have added now, 18.04. I think it is too late to inspect them...

Comment: @guiverc can you please check my update?

Comment: Looks like https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-435/+bug/1846374