# /var taking up too much space

Tags: disk, disk-usage

I got a message that I am running out of space, so I did `du -h` and figured that the `/var` folder was taking 176 GB space! I cleared away all the .gz (gzipped files) but still no improvement!

[image]

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -l /var/log`. And for the file that takes up space `tail -n 100 <filename>`. You probably need to find out what's spamming your logs with information (probably `syslog` or `kern.log`).

Comment: See also [Very large log files, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do)

Comment: To find out what is using up a lot of space: `sudo du | sort -n`. That aggregates on the directory level, whereas in your case it must be files, so `sudo du -a | sort -n` should give you the biggest consumers at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Your `du` output shows that the space is occupied by files in `/var/log` itself, not in some subdirectory.

The next step would be to check that directory for excessively big files. This is most easily done by the command

```
ls -lS | head
```

which shows the nine biggest files in the directory in descending order.

If that doesn't solve the riddle yet then you can run the `tail` command on the biggest one to see its last ten lines.
These will very probably include one or more specimens of the message that's filling your disk.