# Ubuntu 21.10 BTRFS free space on /

Tags: disk-usage, btrfs

I have a problem with free space on btrfs.

```
fecaloid@fecaloid:~/ssd/Host$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /
123M    /boot
782G    /home
22M /etc
4,0K    /media
6,3G    /var
16K /dev
0   /mnt
1,2G    /opt
du: невозможно прочитать каталог '/proc/3477/task/3477/net': Недопустимый аргумент
du: невозможно прочитать каталог '/proc/3477/net': Недопустимый аргумент
du: невозможно получить доступ к '/proc/3832/task/7759/fd/64': Нет такого файла или каталога
du: невозможно получить доступ к '/proc/3832/task/7759/fdinfo/59': Нет такого файла или каталога
du: невозможно получить доступ к '/proc/3832/task/7762/fd/65': Нет такого файла или каталога
du: невозможно получить доступ к '/proc/8529/task/8529/fd/4': Нет такого файла или каталога
du: невозможно получить доступ к '/proc/8529/task/8529/fdinfo/4': Нет такого файла или каталога
du: невозможно получить доступ к '/proc/8529/fd/3': Нет такого файла или каталога
du: невозможно получить доступ к '/proc/8529/fdinfo/3': Нет такого файла или каталога
du: невозможно получить доступ к '/proc/8984': Нет такого файла или каталога
0   /proc
8,6M    /root
du: невозможно получить доступ к '/run/user/1000/doc': Отказано в доступе
du: невозможно получить доступ к '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Отказано в доступе
2,7M    /run
9,4G    /snap
0   /srv
0   /sys
72K /tmp
8,4G    /usr
0   /cdrom
807G    /
```

My / part has 40 gb.
Command "du" says that i have ~14-15 gb free.

```
fecaloid@fecaloid:~/ssd/Host$ btrfs fi df /
Data, single: total=34.98GiB, used=27.85GiB
System, single: total=4.00MiB, used=16.00KiB
Metadata, single: total=1.26GiB, used=537.39MiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=62.50MiB, used=0.00B
```

Here i can see used=27.85GiB. So i has ~7GiB free space.

[Ubuntu disk space analizer shows 8.4gb free](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOHsu.png)

Every day several times the /var/log/syslog weighs 8 + GB. I have already put the section cleaning script on the schedule. But I still don't have enough space on the root partition. I have already moved the Posgtgre & Docker repositories to a separate section.

Please help me find desigion

Comment: You have a problem with the log. It has nothing to do with btrfs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Very large log files, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do)

Comment: Why do commands show different results? Which one to believe? I counted all the directories at the root of the system. I must have 15GB of free space, it turns out only 7

Comment: Have you enabled/used `btrfs` compression?  WARNING:  You may not want to enable compression for `/boot`!

Comment: ill try it. thank you

Comment: The problem occurred due to an extension to automatically change wallpaper https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/543/backslide/

Comment: thanks all for help