# var/log/ is getting very big

Tags: storage

So I looked and examine my disk and I figured out that my `var/log/` is taking up about 100+ GB.

How would I reduce the size of my `/var/log/`?

Here are the results of `tail -f /var/log/syslog`

`Mar 22 23:00:21 usr-MS-7C94 kernel: [44313.727104] audit: type=1400 audit(1647961221.527:631876): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=25795 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"`

`Mar 22 23:00:21 usr-MS-7C94 kernel: [44313.727085] audit: type=1400 audit(1647961221.527:631874): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.discord.discord" name="/proc/2611/cmdline" pid=25795 comm="Discord" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0`

Results of `ls -alhS /var/log | more`

```
total 59G
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm              46G Mar 23 19:19 kern.log
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm              13G Mar 23 08:04 syslog.1
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm             808M Mar 22 07:45 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm              48M Mar 20 15:47 kern.log.1
-rw-r-----   1 syslog            adm             1.6M Mar 23 21:42 syslog
```

Results of `ls -lh /var/log`

```
total 59G
-rw-r--r--  1 root              root            6.2K Mar 21 08:13 alternatives.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root              root            8.3K Feb 23 19:46 alternatives.log.1
-rw-r-----  1 root              adm             1.3K Mar 23 09:47 apport.log
-rw-r-----  1 root              adm             5.0K Mar 22 21:52 apport.log.1
-rw-r-----  1 root              adm              988 Mar 21 21:02 apport.log.2.gz
```

OS:
Ubuntu Studio 20.04

Note:

After getting a notification that I am running low on space, I encountered an error while booting up that says
`overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'` which I suspect is a problem connected with my storage problem

and I already deleted my *.gz files

Thank you so much~!

**SOLVED===**

Taken from the suggestions and answers given, I uninstalled the snap version of Discord and replaced it with the *.deb from the main Discord Website

I then executed

```
cd /var/log
sudo su
> lastlog
> wtmp
> dpkg.log 
> kern.log
> syslog
exit
```

Taken from this thread
[Very large log files, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do/)

And report from `ls -alhS /var/log | more` shows smaller sizes of logs and `more /var/log/kern.log`  showed no repeating errors

Comment: The simplest and *least responsible* answer would be "just delete the logs". However, when the log directory is getting big, it's because something is wrong. Which file(s) take up the bulk of the storage? Read those files to determine what errors are being reported, then work to solve those errors. Once the problems are solved, you can reset your `/var/log` directory so that it remains a manageable size going forward 

Comment: is  /var/log is on separate partition or its in root itself.

Comment: var/log/ is with /usr and /home, although I believe it is also at root

Comment: The biggest one is kern.log next is syslog.1 and syslog, and I don't really understand much of what they are reporting

Comment: The logs grow because there are one or more error in your system. Identify and fix the error(s) and  the logs will stop growing large. Maybe update your question with examples on logged errors. so someone can suggest fixes.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `tail -f /var/log/syslog`. Watch the messages displayed on the terminal for a while. Look for repeating messages. [Edit] your question and paste some of the repeating messages. (Please, no more than ten or so lines!)

Comment: Hi there, I have updated my original question, thank you very much.

Comment: @Rei Status please...

Comment: Yes hello, got caught up with some stuff, sorry for the delay, I followed another answer from a similar question and I have now solved it, Thanks everyone for the help <33

Comment: @Rei Just deleting those large log files won't fix the problem.

Comment: Ohh, sure, I'll test the /var/log/kern.log now, thank you

Comment: @Rei Did you review Update #1 in my answer? You have to look at the log files to determine what's causing them to grow so large. Normally you'll see a repeating error message, like the one that you posted from syslog. Your original kern.log was also huge, but you've deleted it, so any evidence is gone... until the error continues. Did you change the Discord app?

Comment: Yes I have and fortunately, there are no repeating errors reported by `more /var/log/kern.log`

Comment: @Rei Did you change the Discord app? Did you recheck syslog?

Comment: Yes I did change the Discord snap to the *.deb variant, `ls -alhS /var/log | more` shows the logs are significantly smaller with the highest being 43M which is syslog.

Comment: @Rei Since you took the advice from my answer, please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, and as always thank you for your help!

Comment: Votre to reopen as https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do is very different, and foremost for an older version of Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re: `overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'`

Let's first check your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

/var/log/syslog is showing that the snap version of the nasty `Discord` program is acting up. /var/log/kern.log may show the same.

The snap version of `Discord` tries to work outside of its sandbox, and spams syslog and auth.log. Suggest removing the snap version `sudo snap remove discord`, and installing the APT/DEB version... https://discord.com/download. Otherwise you'll need to allow `Discord` privs that are normally not granted to shut it up.

If you show me the first 5 lines of output of `ls -alhS /var/log | more` I suspect that syslog and auth.log are probably very large. After removing the snap version of `Discord`, and installing the APT/DEB version of `Discord`, you can delete these large log files with:

`sudo rm -i /var/log/syslog*`

`sudo rm -i /var/log/auth.log*`

`sudo rm -i /var/log/kern.log*`

Comment: Hi there, this really helped to clear some storage but my /var/log is still 67GB, is it really that big?

Comment: @Rei Edit your question and show me the first 5 lines of output of `ls -alhS /var/log | more`. See Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: @Rei Your /var/log/kern.log is large. Do `more /var/log/kern.log` and look for similar repeating messages... they might be from Discord... or something else... but we need to find out... before we delete the file. Report back.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ sudo du -h /var/log/ | sort
...
$ journalctl --vacuum-time=10d
```

The first will tell you the approximate sizes of the subfolders of /var/log

The second will clean up the .../journal/ folder (keeping ten days worth of logs), which seems to be the most voluminous, locally here.

The journalctl is what I do in conjunction with (almost daily) updates.

---

To see the bytecount sizes of LARGEST files in e.g. `/var/log/` you can do:
`$ find /var/log/ -type f -printf "%-16s %p\n" | sort -n`

Add `... | tail -n 20` to limit it to the 20 largest.

Comment: Ohh thank you for that, it would really help me, although /var/log/ is still about 67GB, but journal is just about 4GB

Comment: `ls -lh /var/log` to find the biggest files (not folders)