# Auto fills root storage problem

Tags: root, storage

After install ubuntu every things is perfect but root partition storage consumption is Rising automatically and it fills the root of 150GB in 40 min and it make the ubuntu unusable and stuck in black screen. How to solve this.
I am new to linux.

Comment: Find what consumes the most space with e.g. `du -ha / |& awk '/^[[:digit:]]+G/' | sort -k1,1nr`

Comment: Graphically, you can use `ncdu`. This looks like a bad service endlessly writing errors to log files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Very large log files, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515146/very-large-log-files-what-should-i-do)